# Suggestions for complicated math concepts that a child can understand

Tags: self-learning, learning

My son really loves math (so do both his parents, for that matter), and does well at it in school.  I will give him math puzzles or tricks now & again, as well as introducing him to Khan Academy and some similar sites.

But I was trying to think of some advanced mathematical concepts that are typically introduced much later, simply because fewer people study them, but not because they inherently require a huge amount of previous knowledge.  I wanted to ask this community for some ideas.  Let me give some ideas of the sort of thing I was thinking of at potential ideas:

- graph theory
- set theory
- combinatorics
- sequences & series
- etc.

I don't mind if the concepts are tough, per se, I just don't want topics that require a huge amount of prior knowledge.  E.g., I'm a statistician, and matrices, Bayesian inference, etc. all require quite a bit of prior understanding.  Whereas, on the flip side, my son loved learning things like fibonocci sequence because it didn't require a huge set of previous knowledge.

If it matters, he is now in 4th grade, but maybe has the math knowledge of a 5th or 6th grader.

I plan on taking one concept that seems to make the most sense (and that he sounds excited about), and drill down into that one.  I don't want to hit him broadside with 4 or 5 different topics that we just cover in a cursory manner.

Thanks!

Comment: Once again I suggest [How to Prove It: A Structured Approach](http://www.amazon.com/How-Prove-It-Structured-Approach/dp/0521675995), by [D.J. Velleman](http://www.cs.amherst.edu/~djv/).

Comment: Some cities have math circles where kids (elementary through high school) meet once a week to learn interesting math topics like you are talking about.  A good example is the Towers of Hanoi puzzle, which is accessible to children.  If your child can't attend a math circle, maybe you can get copies of the worksheets used at math circles and work through them together.  Also check out the curriculum at [artofproblemsolving.com](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/) and their [Beast Academy](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Store/beastacademy.php) which is aimed at elementary school students.

Comment: @littleO Thanks!  I will check out some local groups.  We're in the Bay Area, so there are plenty, I'm sure.  Even at his school.  But now I'm thinking maybe I just set something like this up with him & his friends.

Answer (score 3):

From teaching and from this site, what is clear is that today's student has limited ability to visualize in three dimensions, little ability to even draw the graph of a function on xy axes on graph paper. all that has been relegated to computer screens.. My actual advice, which is what i did for my friend who had middle school and grade school children, was to get construction toys. I like Zometool, http://zometool.com/ , I like those sticks-with-magnets sets. And i really like compass and straightedge with thin cardboard for making Platonic solids. i think a fourth grader can handle a real compass without injuring himself, i did.

Anyway, from the experience with Marty's children, i do not really know what kids will do with toys if you do not guide them much. Plus, Marty's kids are all in college and going into computer science anyway. I just know, very well, what today's kids  cannot do. Surely an architect needs to be able to visualize in 3-D, preferably with lots of experience building models? Plus, perhaps more to the point, what are purely visual aspects of probability and statistics? In dimension $n,$ if a point is uniformly distributed in the cube with all coordinates $-1 \leq x_i \leq 1,$ what is the likelihood that it is in the (inscribed) unit ball?

Let's see, stacking spheres. I would use ping pong balls, fewer uncertainties than oranges, less weight than billiard balls. Why does it not really change anything whether we start with the bottom layer arranged in a square or an equilateral triangle?

Probably enough. Write to me if you like. My site profile has enough information to get my email addresses, phone number.

Comment: Thanks!  We already have Zometool.  I'm happy getting & using toys with him, but he actually wants something a bit more in the realm of "solving":  puzzles, and puzzle-like things, etc.  So I'm looking for ways to encourage creative problem solving.